Django fails to correctly link viewable documents stored in a Django model
So I currently have a Django model which correctly references everything passed to my template, except for the link to the document I have uploaded.
The model has been correctly registered in admin.py.
Here is is MRE:
# investors/models.py
from django.db import models


class FinancialStatements(models.Model):

    financials_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/financials/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Financial Statements'


# investors/views.py
from .models import FinancialStatements


def investor_relations(request):

    financials_queryset = FinancialStatements.objects.all()

    context = {
        'financials_queryset': financials_queryset,
    }

    return render(request, 'investors.html', context)


# settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/assets/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'assets'


#investors/templates/investors.html
{% for financials in financials_queryset %}
  <a href="{{financials.financials_upload.url}}">Financial Statement</a>
{% endfor %}

Upon accessing the uploaded file from the model, the URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/documents/financials/<filename>.pdf which is the directory I want to specify, and so is correct.
However, Django is continuing to fail to access the URL from {{financials.financials_upload.url}} when looping through the financials_queryset quertset
My file directory is set up in the following fashion: <ROOT>/assets/documents/financials/**
Whenever I hover over the <a> tag, the message in the bottom of the left corner of the browser fails to return the URL of the document to be viewed. It simply returns http://127.0.0.1:8000/investors
Despite this, I do fail to see how cannot work this one out, despite correctly point it to the correct directory. Especially when this is correctly viewable from my Django model.
What am I missing here?
**As a side note, if anybody can show me how to illustrate a proper directory tree diagram on here, that would be much appreciated.

If you look at the actual HTML source of the page, e.g. via "View Source" (or the browser inspector), what does the <a href="..."> tag say? I'd bet it's <a href="">, i.e. there is no URL; that'd be the case if there is no file associated. If that's the case, that'll help debug further.

Secondly: what do you mean with "this is correctly viewable from my Django model"? As in, you can see the file in a model instance in the Django admin, or e.g. in the Django shell?

@AKX For your first point, you are correct, for your second question, when I go into the model instances in the Django admin, and you click on the link, it will correctly show the documents uploaded.

Okay. I'm unable to reproduce this with your MRE – I set up a new Django project, copied your code in, created & ran migrations, created an instance of the model in the admin, uploaded a file I had lying around on my desktop, and navigating to /investors (which I'd set up in urls.py) has my markup showing <a href="/assets/documents/financials/00034-20241021091434-3603996476.jpg">Financial Statement</a>.

Well its a fully reproducible MRE, so I fall to see how this is an issue...

Well, the issue is that I can't reproduce the problem with the code you're showing  You can find my repo over at https://github.com/akx/so79223333 if it helps you any.

As for the filetree, you can use the linux command tree, and copy that as a code block.

@TheFlyingPrussian Did you manage to resolve this?

@AKX I did, I will put the answer up tomorrow

@TheFlyingPrussian: two days later...
